# How can I display the output(HTML) depending on its id on node js using sqlite

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite

Here is my code on Node JS. And can you give an example what will i add in the HTML code. Thank you

```js
exports.get = function(req, res){
  db.all("SELECT * FROM f11", function(err,rows){
   rows.forEach(function (row) {
          console.log('row: ' + row.GIVENNAME);
        });
  //  console.log(rows);
    res.render('form11.ejs',{array:rows});
  });
  
};
```

Comment: what do you want to do? Its not clear.

Comment: What will be the correct code for the exports.get function, the query to be exact (SELECT * FROM f11 WHERE id=???? i dont know how to

Comment: are you passing the id in the request?

Comment: Yes, i would like to know what will be the correct code for the query

Comment: which package are you using for sqlite?

Comment: i am asking you, which package are you using for `sqlite` in `nodejs`.

Comment: are you not using any package specially for sqlite in your express node server?

Comment: var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var form11 = require('./databases/form11');

var app = express();

Comment: var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');
var http = require('http');

Comment: can you post your `app.js` or `server.js` file. Also, if you have some other files which handle your routes, post that too.

Comment: can u give me your email? i will send there the files, i only have 6 reputation here

Comment: already copied. thanks

Comment: already sent an email thanks again

Comment: i didnt receive your file becase of some potential security issue, Try compressing (.zip) and then send. Read this before sending :https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?p=BlockedMessage&visit_id=1-636204102126183391-3059079680&rd=1

Comment: i already sent an email. Dont consider the 11files i sent. consider the latest mail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using [sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) npm package for sqlite.

After looking at your code, You can try this to achieve what you want:

change `get` `route` to have a param `id` like this in your `server.js`

```
app.get('/legone/survey/surveyform/form11/:id', form11.get);
```

And, write your `get` function like this:

```
exports.get = function(req,res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    db.all("SELECT * FROM f11 WHERE id = ?",id, function(err,rows){
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
           console.log('row: ' + row.GIVENNAME);
        });
        res.render('form11.ejs',{array:rows});
    });
};
```

And your `route` will be something like this:

```
http://localhost/legone/survey/surveyform/form11/23
```

where 23 is the `id`. Put whatever you want in its place.

if you are using `ajax` calls, it will look like this:

```
$http.get('/legone/survey/surveyform/form11/23')
    .success(function(response){
        //handle response
    })
    .error(function(error){
        //handle error
    });
```

you can test the route via [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) or something like that.

For more information, you can Read [Sqlite3 Wiki API Documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) or, directly about params and Callbacks [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseallsql-param--callback).

Also, after looking at your code you need lot of restructuring. You should define all your routes in one file and then use it inside app.js.

Something like this  :

```
//define all the routes that start from '/legone/survey/surveyform' in one file
//(let it be 'surveryRoutes.js') 
//and then include it in your app.js.
var surveyRoutes = require(./routes/surveyRoutes);
app.use('/legone/survey/surveyform',surveyRoutes);
```

Comment: Thanks i think it worked. Thanks a lot man how can i recommend u

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an id and query on that then:

First you'll need to pass an id in the request query. Like http://localhost/api/getUser?id=23

```
exports.getUser = function(req, res){
   var user_id = req.query.id;
   db.all("SELECT * FROM f11 WHERE id="+user_id, function(err,row){

     console.log(row); // Since you'll only get one row

     res.render('form11_detail.ejs',{data:row});
   });

};
```

If you add this code then for displaying only one you could use 'getUser' function and for displaying all data, you could use your 'get' function.

Comment: the link is unavailable, is it really '+user_id' in the query and 'data' in the render part?